# HTML + Add input field inside a dropdown box

Tags: jquery, html

A new idea came across my mind.Someone may have implemented this. I am trying to get a way to add a textbox inside a dropdown list.

Means I want to add a input box inside a dropdown list. For example :

```
<select id='country'>
  <option value='USA'>USA</option>
  <option value='UK'>UK</option>
  <option value='Russia'>Russia</option>
  <option><input type='text' /></option> // Here I want to add dynamic country 
                                            using ajax but I am able to render
                                            this dropdown.
</select>
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to execute this? I do not want to use any modal box or input box outside this dropdown. I just want to add the value inside the dropdown and press the enter key to add in DB. I'm not worried about the server-side code. I want to be able to render the dropdown only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'd better to create a select box with `div` by yourself instead of tag select.

Comment: Maybe a plugin like `Select2` can implement this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You cannot do that. [Option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) cannot contain any other elements other than text content.

You may instead want to look at some custom plugins, or create your own to render div/spans out of the select that you provide.

> Permitted content Text with eventually escaped characters (like é).

Just one example using **[bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns)**'s dropdown. You can customize and style it accordinf to your need.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7dc/)

Little bit of customization like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/L6YVc/)**

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function () {
     $('.dropdown-toggle b').remove().appendTo($('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text()));
 });
```

Comment: Means option will not provide any way to add input box. So any idea about plugin ?

Comment: @Napster Yes you cannot do that in any means with option, instead try create a jquery plugin yourself which will render select that you provide as input to div/span with a text and probably a data-attribute for the one where you need a input box so that it renders an input inside that span.

Comment: @Napster Just added a simple example using bootstrap dropdown. Probably you can think something on those line or build a plugin yourself or look for some suitable plugins.

Comment: +1 Awesome suggestion ... I am trying my luck to add your suggestion in project.

Comment: Same here.. Bootstrap is awesome tool for developer rather than depending on any designer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add `input element` in a `drop down element`, for this you can create a custom drop down like, by using `ul li` in which you can add a `text field` in it.
Or you can add an `other option` on selecting other you can show a `text box` near by the `drop down option`

like

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()=='other')
    {
        $('#otherTextBox').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#otherTextBox').val('').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way out is to use an autocomplete which has ul and li's or you can have an external input box and an add to list button which would add the text to the list

```
<select id='country'>
    <option value='USA'>USA</option>
    <option value='UK'>UK</option>
    <option value='Russia'>Russia</option>
    <option><input type='text' /></option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="" id="addOptionValue" /> 
<input type="text" value="" id="addOption" />
<input type ="button" value="addOption" id="insertOption" />
```

In Jquery,

```
$('input#insertOption').click(function(){
    var currentHtml = $.trim($('input#addOption').val());
    var currentVal = $.trim($('input#addOptionValue').val());
    if (currentVal  === '' || currentHtml  === ''))) {
        alert('Please enter value');
        return false;
    }
    $('select#country').append('<option value="'+currentVal+'">'+currentHtml+'</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a <datalist> element would fit perfectly here.
You don't need any jQuery or javascript:

```
<input list="country-list" id="country"/>
<datalist id="country-list">
    <option value="USA">
    <option value="UK">
    <option value="Russia">
</datalist>
```

More infos [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

I'm 8 years late, but I think this might help those who are looking for a similar thing even today :)

Comment: Even though its 8year old, happy to see your contribution

Comment: Even in this solution, could not add input box inside dopdown

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried implementing this yet so I don't know that it's 100% correct but you could position a hidden (read display:'none';) input box on top of the select.

**HTML**

```
<select id="country">
   <option value="INP">Input Value</option>
   <option value="USA">USA</option>
   <option value="MEX">Mexico</option>
   <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
</select><br/>
<input type="text" id="countryInput"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#countryInput{ display:'none';position:relative;top:-15px;}
```

Use jQuery to show the input box on selecting a particular value from the dropdown (and hide for all other values).

```
$(function(){
   $('#country').on('change',function(){
      if(this.val()==="INP"){
         $('#countryInput').prop('display','');
      } else {
         $('#countryInput').prop('display','none');
      }
   });
});
```

Then write a function to add the result to the dropdown if you wish.