# can we add textbox and button to select 2

Tags: angularjs-select2

here i attached the code of select can we add the textbox and button into select2 elements.
here which i used a code:

```
<select style="width:100%"  id="e9">

    <option value="volvo">Suger</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>

</select>
```

here i attached the output image how i really want:
[image: text box with button in select 2]

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227982/html-add-input-field-inside-a-dropdown-box) should sort you out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the answer...

```
 $(".select2-drop").append('<div><input type="text" style="width: 86%;padding: 9px;"name="lname"><input class="PrimaryBtn" type="submit" value="Add"></div>');
```

Comment: watch out for adding your textbox and button to multiple select2 widgets.

Comment: yeah...it's add to every..element of select 2

Answer (score 0):

`$("#e9").select2("container").find("div.select2-drop").append('<div><input type="text" name="lname"><input class="PrimaryBtn" type="submit" value="Add"></div>');`

may be this will help, it will add to the needed select2 only