# How can I add the custom button in the select box?

Tags: jquery-select2

How can I add the custom button in the select box? Just like the clear button?

Because I'm using ajax, and want to save cache in the browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BBgk.png)

Comment: you can append it (button snippet) on your result.

Comment: my bad.. you wanted it to be in select box.. I thought you want to add it on the result drop down just like what I did before "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977400/how-to-add-button-to-a-select2-dropdown-on-a-dynamic-table"

Comment: Sorry, I want the button add in the in the select box, no the drop down box. Just like the clear button.

Comment: Actually, I'm using the array/json source, and this array get as ajax from server, and save in the browser. I want a refresh button if I want to manually clear cache and reload again. For the array source, I don't know how to add a button in the drop down box also.

Comment: you should find the answer with below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438381/can-we-add-textbox-and-button-to-select-2