# Combobox with optional input field

Tags: jquery, html

I have seen combobox's where the main field is input with a dropdown underneath it. But could I possible have a dropdown with an item called "other" that when selected makes the main field a input?

Comment: If you could provide a minimum amount of code, Id be happy to help.  Or somewhere youve see this done and add a screen shot.

Comment: UPS.. I think it has been answered here.. Sorry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry

Comment: and here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227982/html-add-input-field-inside-a-dropdown-box