# how to add textbox in dropdown select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to add textbox in dropdown but textbox is not visible in dropdown below is the picture of desired output

[image: this my desired output]

```js
 $.each(SegGoalData, function(i, v) {
   $("#Select").append("<option value=" + SegGoalData[i][0] + ">" + SegGoalData[i][1] + "</option>"); // i am adding value to dropdown
   $("#Select").append("<option><input type='text' name='fname'></option>"); // i am trying to append to textbox
 })
```

```html
<select id="Select">

  <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Look here for more goals</option>

</select>
```

Comment: is your purpose is just search in dropdown options?

Comment: no if user option is not available in dropdown he can mention his desired option in  textbox  inside the dropdown

Comment: No you can not do that. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227982/html-add-input-field-inside-a-dropdown-box) for more details.

Comment: Maybe you can check  [select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**select2**](https://select2.github.io/) JS

[**Select2**](https://select2.github.io/) is a fully-featured, rich select replacement / enhancement plugin. It not only restyles your select elements but also extends them with additional functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".custom-select2").select2();
});
```

```css
.custom-select2{width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

<select class="custom-select2">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
</select>
```

Much like other advanced select plugins, it packs in a whole heap of customizable feature such as:

- Single select element / element with optgroups
- Multi-select element
- Sortable / filterable search field for select elements
- Ability to load data from a remote data source (e.g from an API to dynamically change options)
- Tagging support (selecting from a predefined list / adding dynamic tags on the fly)

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, because browser native UI does not support that functionality, therefore you will have to do a custom UI, or use a library which is already done this for you. as Mention above. https://select2.github.io/ is your best option, there may be other libraries that can do this.

They will replace your `<select>...</select>` tag with their own HTML.

You will have to be very careful, with this if you are loading using ajax, you will have to re-instantiate it each time, if you choose to load it using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can't for now. Just use a dedicated searchable dropdown plugin ([Choosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), etc...), or make your own :)

However, Mozilla is already working on this feature :
[Bug 1309935 - Add ability to find within select dropdown when over 40 elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1309935) (view [specs](https://bug1091592.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8776005))