# How can I add value fields to the drop down items?

Tags: drop-down-menu, paypal

I have a drop down with Small Medium and Large (code below).
I want to capture some text for each line - e.g. Small Tom; Medium Dick; Large Harry.

Supplementary question - can I get more than one name per size - e.g. Small Quantity 3 ;Tom, Dick, Harry

```
 <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="B98VUHC4Y2HSU" />
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Size" />Size
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="os0"> 
<option value="Small (S)">Small (S)  </option>  
<option value="Medium (M)">Medium (M) </option> 
<option value="Large (L)">Large (L) </option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
</table><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" 
name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
<img alt="" border="0"     src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif"
width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. Check out some information referenced [here in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227982/html-add-input-field-inside-a-dropdown-box). You could try using some sort of bootstrap version of it. It isn't possible with just HTML.

As for that extra question, would you want to? You would have to parse through the return string to separate the values.

Here is a Bootstrap version of it from that thread.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav" role="navigation">
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" id="drop2" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">--Select Country--<b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">USA</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">UK</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Russia</a>

            </li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Others <input type="text" id="other"/></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
 $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 });
$('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(){

$('.dropdown-toggle b').remove().appendTo($('.dropdown-toggle').text($(this).text()));
});
```

[Bootstrap JS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7dc/)

Comment: Thank you.Since it's nearly Christmas I'll tell you! Dad want to enter his family in our Santa Dash - 2 small 2 medium Santa suits to be supplied and maybe 4 certificates. If I can download the text string I can parse it if they can type commas.

Answer (score 0):

I accept that what I asked for is not possible or at least not in my competence. 
I have realised that what I really want is different The more I thought about it the easier it got.
But for any future enquirer 
I need to add one line in the cart for each unique combination of two variables OS0 (Size) and OS1 (Name) and Paypal does that anyway. Only if the pair are duplicated does it bump up the quantity on the existing line.
I call this one closed